# How can I avoid an Excessive Grant warning here? Or do I even need to worry about it?

Tags: sql-server, memory

I've written a Stored Procedure that expects a VARCHAR representing some data in XML format. Here is an example of same:

```
'<Documents><Filters><DocClasses><DocClass Value="QUO" /></DocClasses></Filters></Documents>'
```

I process the XML to fill a Table Variable:

```
DECLARE @DocClassesFiltered        BIT
DECLARE @DocClasses                TABLE
       ([DocClass]                 VARCHAR(3)           PRIMARY KEY)
SET @DocClassesFiltered = 0
```

I use sp_xml_preparedocument etc which is bog standard so I won't bore you by documenting this. Suffice to say that I keep its handle in a variable named @idoc

I then populate the Table Variable as follows:

```
IF EXISTS
  (SELECT TOP 1 1
     FROM OPENXML(@idoc, 'Documents/Filters/DocClasses/DocClass', 2)
             WITH([Value]          VARCHAR(3)     '@Value') [DAL])
  BEGIN
    SET @DocClassesFiltered = 1

    INSERT
      INTO @DocClasses
          ([DocClass])
    SELECT [Value]
      FROM OPENXML(@idoc, 'Documents/Filters/DocClasses/DocClass', 2)
              WITH([Value]          VARCHAR(3)     '@Value') [DAL]
  END
```

In the "Actual Execution Plan" output, this produces the warning
**The query memory grant detected "ExcessiveGrant", which may impact the reliablity. Grant size** .... (etc)

My questions:
1) Do I even need to worry about this?
2) If so, how can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite your code on utilising XML methods, such as `value()`? Does it result in the same warning?

Comment: Hello Roger Wolf - The XML isn't the issue; Without the Insert statement the SELECT does not cause this Excessive Grant. However, I did find a way around this - if it even IS an issue - see my own answer below....

Answer (score 1):

I prevented the Excessive Grant by first COUNTING the number of rows and then using the result in a TOP. This, apparently, leads to SQL coming up with a much better estimate of the Memory needed and the Excessive Grant warning "goes away".

```
DECLARE @XMLFilterCount      INT

SELECT @XMLFilterCount = COUNT(1)
  FROM OPENXML(@idoc, 'Documents/Filters/DocClasses/DocClass', 2)
          WITH([Value]           VARCHAR(3)     '@Value') [DAL]
IF @XMLFilterCount > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @DocClassesFiltered = 1

    INSERT
      INTO @DocClasses
          ([DocClass])
    SELECT TOP (@XMLFilterCount) [Value]
      FROM OPENXML(@idoc, 'Documents/Filters/DocClasses/DocClass', 2)
              WITH([Value]          VARCHAR(3)     '@Value') [DAL]
  END
```